# Python Requests GET fails after successfull session login

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I'm using the Python Requests library to login to a PHP-WebCMS. So far I was able to login using the post-command with a payload. I am able to download a file.

The problem is: When I'm running the GET-Command just after loggin in via POST it tells me that im not logged in anymore - although I'm still using the same session! Please have a look at the code

```
#Lets Login
with requests.session() as s:
payload = {'username': strUserName, 'password': strUserPass, 'Submit':'Login'}
r = s.post(urlToLoginPHP, data=payload, stream=True)
#Ok we are logged in. If I would run the #DOWNLOADING Files code right here I would get a correct zip file
#But since the r2-Get-Command delivers the "please login" page it doesn't work anymore
r2 = s.get("urlToAnotherPageOfThisWebsite",stream=True)
#We are not logged in anymore

#DOWNLOADING Files: This now just delivers a 5KB big file which contains the content
 of the "please login page"
local_filename = 'image.zip'
# NOTE the stream=True parameter
r1 = s.get(downloadurl, stream=True)
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r1.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I was logged into the Browser and was trying to login via python at the same time. The site noticed that I was already logged in and I misunderstood it.